# hello.py: error: the following arguments are required: -i/--image

Tags: python, argparse

I have taken a piece of code from the web which uses OpenCV to find circles in an image.

```
# import the necessary packages
import numpy as np
import argparse
import cv2

# construct the argument parser and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required = True, help = r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\Sem 8T\Mini Project\Data\Imagestraffic.jpg")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

# load the image, clone it for output, and then convert it to grayscale
image = cv2.imread(args["image"])
output = image.copy()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# detect circles in the image
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1.2, 100)

# ensure at least some circles were found
if circles is not None:
    # convert the (x, y) coordinates and radius of the circles to integers
    circles = np.round(circles[0, :]).astype("int")
    # loop over the (x, y) coordinates and radius of the circles
    for (x, y, r) in circles:
        # draw the circle in the output image, then draw a rectangle
        # corresponding to the center of the circle
        cv2.circle(output, (x, y), r, (0, 255, 0), 4)
        cv2.rectangle(output, (x - 5, y - 5), (x + 5, y + 5), (0, 128, 255), -1)
        
    # show the output image
    cv2.imshow("output", np.hstack([image, output]))
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

However, I keep getting the same error: hello.py: error: the following arguments are required: -i/--image

I've tried ap.parse_args(args) instead of ap.parse_args() but that doesn't seem to solve it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  As your script states, when you run it, you need to include the ```-i``` (or ```-image```) argument as defined in your ```required = True``` inclusion.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @ewong. I tried using ap.parse_args("-i", "--image") but I got an AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'image'. Am I using the wrong type for the argument?

Comment: No, I meant that when you run ```hello.py```, you need to include the ```-i``` argument. i.e.  ```python hello.py -i <image>```

Comment: You need to read more about using scripts that take command line values.  This script expects you to provide the name of an 'image' file.  It will be used in the `cv2.imread(args["image"])` expression.  It is hard to use python code that you find on the web without some basic python knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do it.

```
ap.add_argument("-i",  r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\Sem 8T\Mini Project\Data\Imagestraffic.jpg", required=True,
    help="path to input image")

ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required = True, help = "Path to the image")
```

Answer (score -1):

Hope this will work !

```
# import the necessary packages
import numpy as np
import argparse
import cv2



# load the image, clone it for output, and then convert it to grayscale
image = cv2.imread(r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\Sem 8T\Mini Project\Data\Imagestraffic.jpg")
output = image.copy()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# detect circles in the image
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1.2, 100)

# ensure at least some circles were found
if circles is not None:
    # convert the (x, y) coordinates and radius of the circles to integers
    circles = np.round(circles[0, :]).astype("int")
    # loop over the (x, y) coordinates and radius of the circles
    for (x, y, r) in circles:
        # draw the circle in the output image, then draw a rectangle
        # corresponding to the center of the circle
        cv2.circle(output, (x, y), r, (0, 255, 0), 4)
        cv2.rectangle(output, (x - 5, y - 5), (x + 5, y + 5), (0, 128, 255), -1)
        
    # show the output image
    cv2.imshow("output", np.hstack([image, output]))
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: I'm able to run it without errors. However, the output is not exactly what's desired, but that may be some issue in the code itself. Thanks for your help!